# XSLT and Java: Default Namespace XMLNS

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, prefix

I'm new to XSLT and I'm trying to transform one XML file into another one. My problem is that there is one namespace 'xmlns' without any prefix in the original xml file and when I transform it to another one through xslt then nothing happens but if I remove that xmlns namespace then it works out but actually I cannot modify the original .xml file since I'm bound to use that file only, so I have to keep xmlns in the original file as it is. So can anyone please suggest some modifications in my .xsl or java code to overcome this problem.

My Original XML namespace looks like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <manifest identifier="eXeorm_sample4823c6301f29a89a4c1f"
        xmlns:ims="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
        xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
        xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" 
        xmlns:imsmd="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_v1p2" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
</manifest>
```

My desired xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <manifest identifier="eXescorm_quiz4823c6301f29a8419515" 
            xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" 
            xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" 
            xmlns:imsmd="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_v1p2" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        </manifest>
```

My Modified XSLT-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2"
xmlns:ims="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1" 
xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" 
xmlns:imsmd="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_v1p2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="ims:manifest">   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a search box at the top of this page: type "XSLT default namespace" and you will find hundreds of answers to this question.

Incidentally, your code is incredibly verbose. Instead of this:

```
<xsl:element name="item">
    <xsl:attribute name="identifier">ITEM-eXeorm_sample4823c6301f29a89a4d27</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="isvisible">true</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="identifierref">RES-eXeorm_sample4823c6301f29a89a4d28</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

use this:

```
<item identifier="ITEM-eXeorm_sample4823c6301f29a89a4d27" invisible="true"
      identifierref="RES-eXeorm_sample4823c6301f29a89a4d28"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and suggestion. I had gone through some threads regarding namespace prefix before posting the question but those didn't work out. I'll try now as per your suggestion and get back to you. Thanking you!

Comment: @MichaelKey I have modified my XSLT according to your suggestion and some solutions mentioned the other threads. Now my second issue is solved and I'm not getting adlcp related error but first issue remains as it is. Its not working with default namespace. In my case the value of default namespace is different in both the XML files and it is listed under manifest tag. Please suggest me necessary amendment for that part and if possible please just edit that xmlns part in my code.
Thanking you!

Comment: Dr.Michael I'm able to generate output by keeping default namespace in the original XML file but the output is not exactly same which I want. The declaration area of namespace under manifest tag looks different and some namespace like xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" are added in other tags automatically which are not required. Please suggest me the modifications.
Thanking you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm able to generate the desired result now. :)